# React.js State Object Updated/Changed Async in EventListener But Not Causing a Component Re-Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

I am new to React.  I am trying to integrate an external library written in VanillaJS with my React app.  The external library sets `window.addEventListener()` in one part of its code and makes updates/changes to some object asynchronously.

If I pass in my `state` object from my React app to this external method, I can observe that the state object changes when some relevant event occurs.  For example, I can see this if I wait a couple of milliseconds and then print the state to the console in the React app.  Now, the state is different, but the component doesn't appear to be re-rendering.

```
const myObj = { "counter": 0 }
const [state, SetState] = useState(myObj);

useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(state); -> { "counter": 0 }
    externalLibraryEventListener(state); // externalLibraryEventListener increments myObj["counter"] by 1 asynchronously. 
    // setTimeout(() => {console.log(state)}, 2000) -> { "counter": 1 }
    }
), [state];
```

In my research, I have read so far about React interpreting shallow and deep copies of data differently and responding differently.  I'm not sure if that's what is going on here, but maybe it's the right track.  My other hunch is that it's not re-rendering the component because there isn't any front-end change (like a mouse click or a form filled) which changes the state; from the perspective of the React app, the state object seems to be changing in-memory.

In the end, what I would like is to pass some object from my React app to the VanillaJS code, listen for changes in state, and then for my React app to respond if there is such a change.  Maybe this is not possible given React and after many hours of trying I thought I would ask here.  In coming up with a solution, it would be ideal in my case to handle everything from the React app side without making changes to the VanillaJS code.

Comment: Does this external library have any way to notify you when it has updated? For example, does it return a promise, or let you subscribe for an event callback?

Comment: that is a great question; sadly, it doesn't have support for that.  it just updates (increments a property of) some in-memory object.  it may be that I need to make one of those changes for this use case (but I'd prefer not to, if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react there is exactly one way to cause a rerender: you must call setState. Additionally, the value you pass in to setState must be a new value (as identified by an [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) check, which is similar to `===`). So if the state is an object, you need to set it to a new object, not mutate an old object.

Ideally, this external library has some way to tell you when it makes a change, and then you can act on that to call setState. Something like this (i'm inventing the external library code):

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = externalLibrary.onChange((newValue) => {
    setCounter(newValue);
  });
  return unsubscribe
}, []);
```

If the library has no way to tell you when a change happens, you're going to have to get creative. If the library is writing to a property of the object, maybe you could craft an object with a setter function and use that as a way to get notified.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const interceptor = {
    _counter: 0;
    get counter() {
      return this._counter;
    },
    set counter(newValue) {
      this._counter = newValue;
      setCounter(newValue);
    }
  }
  externalLibraryEventListener(interceptor);
}, []);
```

Your code had a commentted out bit with a setTimeout. That might be an option as well: polling for changes, then setting state. I don't think that's the best solution since it will introduce a delay before you notice the change, and you'll have cases where you do work to check for a change but nothing happened.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const myObj = { counter: 0 }
  externalLibraryEventListener(myObj);

  let prevValue = 0;
  const id = setInterval(() => {
     if (myObj.counter !== prevValue) {
       setCounter(myObj.counter);
       prevValue = myObject.counter;
     }
  }, 500);

  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, []);
```

In my examples i've deliberately changed the state to be a number instead of an object. If you need to keep it as an object for some reason, keep in mind that you must make a new object each time you set state. Mutating the same object will look to react like nothing has changed. So if you need to set state using that object, make sure to copy it first

```
setState({ ...stateWhichWasMutated });
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!!  I'll take a look at some of your suggestions